# SQLite DB file is not encrypted in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, sqlcipher, sqlite-net

I am using [sqlite-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library to encrypt my local db using SQLCipher. In the followign image, the ExecuteDBCode gets called from AppDelegate class and left side you can see the nuget packages added to the project. When I run the code on iOS simulator, the Encrypted.db file is created but it's not encrypted. I can explore it on DB browser without any password.

[image]

I am using legacy Xamarin.iOS project and running on iPhone 14 simulator and running on 16.4 version.